# How to make sure a function is always terminated in case callback is not called in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, terminate

My main function run n tasks. Ideally, when such n tasks are done, a callback function of the main function will be called to terminate the whole process. However, some of those n tasks sometimes don't finished (no callback in each task is called), thus prevent main function from terminating?

Is there any way to make sure each task in those n tasks always finishes (callback is called) in case is callback is not called?

Comment: Use [tag:node-async] with something like setTimeout, or a proper timeout module that handles long-running functions.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, I cannot find proper module by myself. Can you recommend me any module and its usage? @remus

Answer (score 1):

This is a hard question without any specific code because the ways to address this issue are all related to specific code.  The best way to fix it would be to go into each specific operation and make sure that the callback is always called (fix the bug that causes it to not be called).  Then, you can reliably use the code everywhere without this issue.

If you can't go into the code itself, then all you can really do is to set a timer and if the callback hasn't been called in some time period (that you define), then you can call the callback yourself with a timeout error.  You could do this by hooking the function so you can intercept the callback to know when it's been called and how to call it with the timeout error.

If you can provide actual code for the situation you're trying to fix, then we can provide much more specific code in an answer.

Comment: Sorry for replying late.
I just figured out the main problem of my program. It's because I send to many requests to a server. In some requests, the callback in "request(url, function (error, response, html) {})" is not called (I wait for a long time, but I still cannot see the callback is called). My program has to deal with a huge number of requests. A solution could be to process those requests one by one or by time interval of 1s or 2s,...but it will waste a lot of time. Is there any other solution?

Comment: @MrCold - If you don't control the server, a usual solution is to limit the number of requests you send to X at a time where X is a value that you have tested works with your server infrastructure.  You can implement this in your own code by keeping a counter of "in-flight' requests and every time one finishes, you launch a new one.  The async library has a feature called `.eachLimit()` that does this kind of thing for you.

Comment: @MrCold - Also my guess is that your code somewhere is ignoring some sort of error because a request should not just disappear.  Proper code will either finish the request or report an error.  This probably also should be fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming these are all asynchronous, I'd try out Bluebird and use Promises.
You can use Promise.settle to make sure everything finishes, whether the Promise is fulfilled or not.

https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#settle---promise

Comment: Switching to promises won't help if the callback is never called.  `.settle()` helps in situations where you just want to know when a group of promises are done no matter whether they completed successfully or with errors.  If the promise never resolves or rejects, `.settle()` won't fire either.